# Delegating to async subgenerators

Tags: python, asynchronous, generator, python-asyncio

[PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) introduced `yield from` to let a generator delegate to a subgenerator.
Notably, `send()`, `throw()` or `close()` calls on the delegating generator will be forwarded to the subgenerator:

```py
def gen1():
    res = yield 1
    print('Received:', res)
    res = yield 2

def gen2():
    yield from gen1()

g = gen2()
print(g.send(None))
print(g.send('msg1'))
```

prints

```
1
Received: msg1
2
```

[PEP 525](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/) introduced asynchronous generators, which are able to await on async coroutines and yield results that can be awaited by the consumer. Like generators, async generators can also receive values sent using `asend()` (and support `athrow()`/`aclose()`).

**Is there a way to delegate to async subgenerators?** The following does not work: the subgenerator doesn't receive the sent value, because `asend()` is not forwarded. It could be done manually in `agen2`, but `yield from` has spoiled us with its simplicity. Does anything like `async yield from` exist?

```py
async def agen1():
    res = yield 1
    print('Received:', res)
    res = yield 2

async def agen2():
    async for x in agen1():
        yield x

async def consumer():
    ag = agen2()
    print(await ag.asend(None))
    print(await ag.asend('msg1'))

import asyncio
asyncio.run(consumer())
```

Output:

```
1
Received: None
2
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

According to PEP 525 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#asynchronous-yield-from `async yield from` "would require a serious redesign of the generators implementation."

Comment: Thanks! The next paragraph of the PEP is saying that "to compose asynchronous generators a simple async for loop can be used" but my example is showing that this doesn't work with asend (or athrow).